# Django Spam URL blocker form entering into my application

Tags: python, django, web-applications

I have a Django application that is working fine. Now after some time, I come across some spam URLs that are getting processed by my application. Is there any way I can block these particular URLs from entering into my application? Is there any predefined middleware or library for doing this task?

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you give examples of the spam urls? any patterns or anything?

Comment: let's say it's: http://127.0.0.1:8000/home/spam/7383. I don't want this particular URL to enter into my application. I want it to get blocked in the very first place. Is there any library we can use to get this done?